# How can I install something on Travis CI without a timeout?

Tags: scipy, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am trying to test a package build on travis-ci.org, but am coming up against a timeout with pip install scipy:

```
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy
    Running command /home/travis/virtualenv/python2.6.9/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-Fn2gmJ/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hWDx9L-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/travis/virtualenv/python2.6.9/include/site/python2.6


No output has been received in the last 10 minutes, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.

The build has been terminated
```

(extract from a recent [build log](https://travis-ci.org/gwpy/gwpy/jobs/52225518)).

How can I build scipy >= 0.11 on Travis without a timeout?

Comment: relevant Travis issue for pre-installed `scipy` support: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2650

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution is straightforward. Just prefix the installation command with **travis_wait**. More details are available at [https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#Build-times-out-because-no-output-was-received).

Answer (score 12):

The default timeout per command on Travis is 10 minutes and when you use the function **travis_wait** only, the timeout is 20 minutes. If your build need wait more than 20 minutes, you can pass a number of minutes to function **travis_wait**, exemple:

```
$ travis_wait 30 pip install scipy
```

This is a function undocumented in Travis, but it is suggested by Hiro Asari from Travis on [github issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/3161).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [an approach from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983048/passing-a-string-with-spaces-as-a-function-argument-in-bash), if using the commands like `travis_wait` provided by `Travis CI` isn't an option.

In my case I wanted to keep Travis running while defining steps in separate shell scripts where I had no idea how to use Travis-provided commands. The approach above worked out pretty well (if interested see [the pull request](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_ci/pull/43)).