# Travis build stucks on jacoco

Tags: travis-ci

This is my travis.yml

```
language: java

sudo: required

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

install: true

script:
  - sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
  - java -version

after_success:
- ./gradlew test jacocoTestReport coveralls
```

And this is the travis output:

```
[...]
:processTestResources
:testClasses
:test
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.build/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.build-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.jar
No output has been received in the last 10 minutes, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.
The build has been terminated
```

I have no idea why and how I can debug this :\ any hints?
Works on my machine.

Comment: Try running your Gradle part first with either -i / --info (to show some info) or if required, --debug option for running jacocoTestReport task. Also, try to see if it's due to a large source code in your project and analyze the output of --info / --debug to find out the root cause. I'd also try to use different/newer version of jacoco 0.7.5 or 0.7.x newer than what you are using. Are you using jmockit? if yes, make sure you are using a compatible version of jacoco and jmockit.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out it has nothing to do with jacoco. I'm using JavaFX with TestFX and, of course, it needs a frame buffer. It works after enabling xvfb.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install something on Travis CI without a timeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746046/how-can-i-install-something-on-travis-ci-without-a-timeout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it has nothing to do with jacoco. I'm using JavaFX with TestFX and, of course, it needs a frame buffer. It works after enabling xvfb:

```
before_install:
  - "export DISPLAY=:99.0"
  - "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"
```